Can wall tile be used on fireplace hearth?
My family owns an historic 1890 home. We are trying to bring back some of the original charm that was lost over the years and are planning on installing new tile to the fireplace surround and the hearth in front of the fireplace. However, everything we like tile-wise is rated only for wall use. Can we use wall graded tile on the hearth? No one really walks on it, but obviously it's a possibility that someone might step on it from time to time. TIA!

Most floor tile wants a very solid and flat sub floor.  This usually requires almost 1.5 inch plywood sheets(two 3/4 inch sheets).  The odd step and built very solid, wall tiles might last.

It's your home. You can do as you wish. However you run a risk that the tile can crack if it is subjected to more pressure than it is rated for.
No one here can answer if the aesthetic value of the wall tile you wish to use, is worth the risk.
